# Javascript Countdown not working

Tags: javascript, dom, timer, windows-runtime, winjs

I have this javascript code

```
 function updateClock() {
        time = time + 1;
       var  mins = 1;
       var secs = 50
       var mins = parseInt(mins/ 60);
       var secs = time - mins * 60;

        mins = mins.toString();
        secs = secs.toString();

        if (mins.length < 2)
            mins = "0" + mins;
        if (secs.length < 2)
            secs = "0" + secs;


        var timeDisp = document.getElementById("timerDisp");
        timeDisp.innerText = mins + ":" + secs;
    }
```

It is counting how much time has passed, but what if I want to do a countdown? (or do the reverse) instead of keeping track of the time, I want to give if a definite time then as time goes by the time decreases, let's say 1 minute and 15 seconds, how would I execute that on the given code?

Comment: It's not working because it's a stopwatch, not a timer. Have you tried to modify the code?

Comment: I did, but it is still doing the same thing. I tried setting a definite time but it keeps ending on the same result

Comment: Post your current code. That should be easier to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute your `updateClock()` every 1 second with `setTimeout()` to create a countdown.

```
var time;
function UpdateClock() {
    time = time - 1;

    if (time > 0) {
        setTimeout(UpdateClock, 1000); // 1000 miliseconds
    }

    var mins = parseInt(time / 60, 10);
    var secs = time - mins * 60;

    mins = mins.toString();
    secs = secs.toString();

    if (mins.length < 2)
        mins = "0" + mins;
    if (secs.length < 2)
        secs = "0" + secs;

    timeDisp.innerText = mins + ":" + secs + " left";
}

function StartCountdown(countdowntime) {
    time = countdowntime;
    updateClock();
}
```

Comment: You might want to move the `setTimeout` call as early in `UpdateClock` as you can. Otherwise the extra processing for the other lines might mean the overall time between 'ticks' is actually slightly longer than 1000ms. Not such a problem in this example but if you're not careful you can end up with a timer that drifts from 'real' time.

Comment: How about for the seconds, how would I display it? i seperate the seconds and minutes

Comment: @KyelJmD Same way you were doing it in your implementation.

Comment: @TimCroydon You're right, it's insignificant for such low timespan but with longer ones it would definitely be taking more than 1 second. I am updating now with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use setInterval() for your countdown. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp.